# How do I properly configure Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PP</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateSession.java

```
public class HibernateSession {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {

            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch ( Throwable ex ) {
            // Log the exception.
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
      {
        return sessionFactory;
      }
}
```

DataFetcher.java used for executing quesries

```
 public class DataFetcher {

        Session session;

        public DataFetcher()
          {
            session = HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          }

        public void Save(Marki m)
          {
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(m);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

          }
    }

ManagedBean(name="dodaj")
@ViewScoped
public class DodajOferte implements Serializable {

    private Marki marka;

    public DodajOferte()
      {

        marka = new Marki();
      }

    public String Dodaj()
      {

        DataFetcher f = new DataFetcher();

        try {
            f.Save(marka);
        } catch ( HibernateException ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage().toString());

            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("err");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, message);
            return null;
        }
        return null;

      }

    public Marki getMarka()
      {
        return marka;
      }

    public void setMarka(Marki marka)
      {
        this.marka = marka;
      }
}
```

How do i properly configure Hibernate? I have problems with almogs every transaction I make!
In this case i get "INFO: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions ". When i `change session.save(m); to session.merge(m);` it works as long as I am on the same page. When i change the page, and then return back to it, I get lots of exceptions.

Comment: looks like merge isnt working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

dont store the session object with your DataFetcher. That's not a good idea. Each session is bound to a transaction which is bound it's thread. I am not sure whether this code runs in a container or not but if so hibernate will try to use the in scope transaction manager and your code will be confusing for that. Change your code to the following and see if that changes anything.

`public class DataFetcher {`

```
    public void Save(Marki m)
      {
        Session session = HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(m);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

      }
}
```